# How to serialise events in javafx?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am trying to create an JavaFX application. As a part of it, I have to draw a circle, if a button is pressed an animation happens, after that I have to draw another circle. But the second circle is drawn before the animation is over. I am trying this for a while with no luck. Any hint is appreciated.

Here draw() will draw initial circle, play() will do animation, drawAfter() has to happen after play(), but it happens before completion of play().

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition.OrientationType;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;



public class CircularPlay extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    TextField tf=new TextField("Write a number");
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, Color.WHITE);
    Button bt=new Button("Start");
    Label label=new Label("change this");
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (50, 50, 5, 5);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(600, 400);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();



    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        bt.setLayoutX(650);
        bt.setLayoutY(50);
        label.setLayoutX(650);
        label.setLayoutY(100);
        rect.setArcHeight(50);
        rect.setArcWidth(50);
        rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);

    }
    private void draw()
    {
        gc.strokeOval(50, 0, 100, 100);
        gc.rect(1, 1, 599, 399);
        gc.stroke();
    }
    private void drawAfter()
    {
        gc.strokeOval(100, 50, 100, 100);
    }
    private void play()
    {
        Path path = new Path();

        path.getElements().add (new MoveTo (50, 50));
        path.getElements().add (new ArcTo(50,50,90,100,100,true,true));

        PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();

        pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        pathTransition.setNode(rect);
        pathTransition.setPath(path);
        pathTransition.setOrientation(OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathTransition.setCycleCount(1);
        pathTransition.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);
        root.getChildren().add(bt);
        root.getChildren().add(label); 

        draw();

        bt.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            label.setText("Accepted");
            play();
            drawAfter();
        });  

        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until the animation ends to draw the second circle.

For that there's a method on every animation: `setOnFinished()`.

In your case, remove `drawAfter(()` from the button listener:

```
bt.setOnAction(e -> {
        label.setText("Accepted");
        play();
    });
```

and add it to the animation:

```
private void play(){
    ...
    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    ...
    pathTransition.setOnFinished(e->drawAfter());
    pathTransition.play();
}
```